# CSS counter-increment - start counter at 100

Tags: html, css, counter

The counter-increment works in my code, but I want to start the counter at 100 on the first section, and 200 on the next.

This is what I got:

```
Chapter>Section>Subsec1>Subsec2>Tit {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size:16px;

    counter-increment: subsection2;
}
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Counter for what? A list, paragraph what?

Comment: Please provide some of your code. Your question makes little sense without it.

Comment: please add link to jsfiddle with code example

Comment: Fredrik Johanssons code worked for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify what the counter should be increased with by adding a number after the counter name, like this:

```
counter-increment: counter-name 100;
```

You can do the same thing with `counter-reset`, but since you want the first incrementation to be 100 you should start at 0

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment

Comment: `counter-reset: numList 1;` is what I wanted. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699608/470749 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset