# ol>li numbering gets messy

Tags: html, css

I am using `ol>li` in an HTML file, added styling to it to use the hierarchical numbering like 1, 1.1,1.2, 1.2.1 etc. It works perfectly fine sometimes, but sometimes the numbering gets messy. Instead of starting with next number, it continues the same hierarchy. Refer the attached image,  [instead of using number 3, the numbering continues as 2.6 and then uses 2.6.1 and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbFvt.png)

here is my css -

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
ol>li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: .6em
}
ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: .3em;
  font-size: 14px;
}
li ol>li {
  margin: 0
}
li ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " "
}
li ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  font-size: small
}

<ol>
    <li>List Item 1
        <ol>
            <li>Indented List Item 1</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 2</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>List Item 2
        <ol>
            <li>Indented List Item 1</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 2</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>List Item 3
        <ol>
            <li>Indented List Item 1</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 2</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>List Item 4
        <ol>
            <li>Indented List Item 1</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 2</li>
            <li>Indented List Item 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: You need to include minimum required code to post question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reset a CSS-counter to the start-attribute of the given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699128/how-can-i-reset-a-css-counter-to-the-start-attribute-of-the-given-list)

Comment: Please see answer below

Comment: Sorry for the delay in adding the css code.

Comment: Can you say anything about when it gets messy? After refreshing, doing things with JavaScript, changing CSS, viewing the page on a different device, zooming in or out etc?

Comment: Nope. On one refresh it works, on another, it doesn't. There is no pattern what so ever!

Answer (score 1):

Here is clean code

```css
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
 <ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
  <ol>
   <li>two.one</li>
   <li>two.two</li>
   <li>two.three</li>
  </ol>
     </li>
  <li>three 
  <ol>
   <li>three.one</li>
   <li>three.two</li>
    <ol>
     <li>three.two.one</li>
     <li>three.two.two</li>
    </ol>
   </ol>
     </li> 
  <li>
  four
  <ol>
     <li>Four.one</li>
     <li>Four.two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: What browser are you using ? As the snippet seems to work just fine.

Comment: I am using chrome and ff now. But it should work on all browser

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/webdevkumar/n2we7220/1/

Comment: Both the snippet and thee fiddle you posted are working fine for me (Firefox)

Comment: Cool... Happy coding mate

Comment: Then upvote the answer mate

Comment: The problem is, my code works in most cases, but sometimes it doesn't. and there are no differences in code, environment, network and browser.

Comment: hmmm.. Maybe css reset or initialization etc....

Comment: @DarshanMane If you can't provide a [mcve], I'm afraid there's not much we can do you help you.

Comment: @MrLister you are right mate

Comment: I thought HTML code would not be needed; but anyway, I have updated the question and not it contains the css as well as HTML code.

Comment: @DarshanMane Now we understand mate... Happy coding once again