# UL act like an OL => including START value

Tags: css

It not usual to do so, but we are getting an unordered list from an external tool and have to deal with it. This is why I am asking here.

I need the ul to behave like an ol.
It's easy to say, list-style-type="decimal".
**But I would need to have the START parameter as well.**

If that is not possible to have in an easy way I would have to build something completly independant, aka

```
<li>
  <span>1.</span>
  <p>Text</p>
</li>
```

I would really like to avoid that, so my question is:

Is it possible to use an ul as an ol including the start value?

```
<ul start="17">
```

Comment: Why not insert it as an `ol` from the start? How do you get that `ul` and how do you insert it into your own HTML ?

Comment: The JS solution from here should be easily adaptable to your needs, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699608/10283047

Comment: @Mihat: I am getting the ul ready to use via an external partner/tool. No change possible. I could only add a class

Comment: @misorude hmm, the ol knows how to handle a start value, ul dies not, so this is not an option at all

Comment: This has nothing to do with what element knows how to handle what, this is simply based on _setting_ the appropriate start value taken from the element, as the start value for a CSS counter.

Comment: I don't see that this js can help for what I am trying to reach. Or I don't understand it. It's not about resetting any values. It's about the behavieour, how an <ol> handles an start value and <ul> on the other hand does not know about start values at all. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The solution is about adding the counter via CSS, instead of relying on the default functionality.

Comment: But it should be easy to handle for a user on the other side of the desk. He should have a tool where he defines e.g. <list start="17"> That's it. He should not handle with css or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**CSS Counters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) and define a starting point in the [**`counter-reset`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset)` CSS.

```css
ul.my-list {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item 17;
  /* number should always be 1 LESS than your required starting number */
}

.my-list li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

> It should be easy to handle for a user on the other side of the desk. He should have a tool where he defines e.g. `<list start="17">` That's it. He should not handle with css or whatever.

That being the case, this [**Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699128/how-can-i-reset-a-css-counter-to-the-start-attribute-of-the-given-list) may offer a solution..the user merely has to apply a `style="--start-xx";` inline style and CSS Custom properties can handle the rest.

```css
ul.my-list {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item calc(var(--start) - 1) 
}

.my-list li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list" style="--start:21">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="my-list" style="--start:10">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that's promising, but the start value has to be dynamic. Is there a way without js?

Comment: How are you planning on getting the start value into the page? You could always add the `style="counter-reset: item 17;"` in the *inline* CSS

Comment: The users will use kind of a "template", where they can add an element named <list> and add a param with value as well. That was the idea for <list start="17"> I don't know if it will work with a style definition as well, I even don't understand how the above sample works. Where do you read (and re-set) the value?

Comment: ah, correction.. I see where you are reading it. Would this work with an (data-)attribute as well, instead of a style?

Comment: Well if you're adding some HTML to the page through this non-html "Template" then I assume you can manage to adjust the template to send what it is you need.... a `ul` since there is no such thing as `list` in HTML. If you can parse `list`=17` into `ul`  then it can't be too much different to parse `start=17` to `style="--start:17"`.

Comment: Nope, attributes don't work, see the linked Q&A. It would be nice, but unfortunately, not.