# TYPO3: CKEditor: Removes attribute in frontend; backend OK

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-10.x

TYPO3 10.4.20

I have styled an ordered list and I want to use a start-number.

In my YAML I have added:

```
editor:
  config:
    extraAllowedContent:
      - ol[*]

# Allow s and u tag
processing:
  allowAttributes: [ data-count, start ]
  HTMLparser_db:
    tags:
      ol:
        allowedAttribs: "start"
```

In the editor everything is fine:

```
<ol start="5">
    <li><strong>Text</strong><br />
    More Text</li>
    <li><strong>Text</strong><br />
    More Text</li>
</ol>
```

The attribute `start="5"` is saved.

But in the frontend the `start="5"` is gone.

What do I need?

Comment: The funny thing is, data-count works, start not.

Comment: Seems to be a CKEditor problem: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1032

Comment: This is exactly what I need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699128/how-can-i-reset-a-css-counter-to-the-start-attribute-of-the-given-list

Answer (score -1):

Try this, add some additional configuration in your preset config. Check it out below:

```
# Load default processing options
imports:
    - { resource: "EXT:web_conf/Configuration/YAML/Processing.yaml" }

# Add configuration for the editor
# For complete documentation see http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
editor:
  config:
    allowedContent: true
    extraAllowedContent: "*(*);*{*}"
    fillEmptyBlocks: false
    tabSpaces: 0
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true
    entities_additional: ''
    removePlugins: null
```

Your processing configuration seems correct. So,let it be.

```
# Allow s and u tag
processing:
  allowAttributes: [ data-count, start ]
  HTMLparser_db:
    tags:
      ol:
        allowedAttribs: "start"
```

This works for me.

Comment: No difference. Backend OK, Frontend start="5" is gone.